Spatially mapping connections in python
I am trying to plot trade routes of commodities from one country to another in Python using plotly. I want the connections to transition from red at the origin to blue at the destination.
However, the connections appear broken (non-straight lines) when I try to interpolate the colors. This could also be due to the map projection I am using. Can someone suggest how to achieve this with smooth, straight lines?
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

# Function to interpolate between two points
def interpolate_points(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, num_points=10):
    lons = np.linspace(lon1, lon2, num_points)
    lats = np.linspace(lat1, lat2, num_points)
    return lons, lats

# Create the figure
fig = go.Figure()

num_segments = 5  # Number of segments to divide each line into
colors = [mcolors.to_hex(c) for c in np.linspace(mcolors.to_rgba('red'), mcolors.to_rgba('blue'), num_segments)]

for i in range(len(Def_trade_Kastner)):
    lon1, lat1 = Def_trade_Kastner['start_lon'][i], Def_trade_Kastner['start_lat'][i]
    lon2, lat2 = Def_trade_Kastner['end_lon'][i], Def_trade_Kastner['end_lat'][i]
    lons, lats = interpolate_points(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, num_points=num_segments)
    
    for j in range(num_segments - 1):
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scattergeo(
                lon=[lons[j], lons[j + 1]],
                lat=[lats[j], lats[j + 1]],
                mode='lines',
                line=dict(width=Def_trade_Kastner['Relative Emissions'][i],
                          color=colors[j]),
                showlegend=False
            )
        )

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Deforestation',
    showlegend=False,
    geo=dict(
        visible=False,
        showcountries=True,
        projection_type='equirectangular',  
        landcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)',
        countrycolor='rgb(204, 204, 204)',
    ),
)

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1200,
    height=700,
)

fig.show()

Longer connections are the ones where such trends are most apparent. E.g., 'Brazil to China' or 'USA to Indonesia'. Please see below:

You can use the following demo DataFrame points to check connections:
Def_trade_Kastner = pd.DataFrame({
    'Producer country': ['Brazil', 'Indonesia'],
    'Consumer country': ['China', 'United States'],
    'Relative Emissions': [10, 2.047066],
    'start_lat': [-10.333333, -2.483383],
    'start_lon': [-53.200000, 117.890285],
    'end_lat': [35.000074, 39.78373],
    'end_lon': [104.999927, -100.445882]
    })


Since there is no data to reproduce your question, I have an example of visualization of arrival and departure frequencies at a US airport as a reference example. I assume yours is also based on this example. I have modified it to fit your code. I checked its output graph and did not find the issue you pointed out to be a very significant challenge.

Hi @r-beginners. Thank you for providing suggestion. I have now added the demo dataframe to plot the connections. Please see my question. I tried your present code and it doesn't work. You could see the same problem when you zoom-in. You couldn't see it earlier because the map was not plotted over a large region to see the breaks.

Based on the added data, I tried the map projection method available in Plotly. Given that the spherical projection is closer to the intended representation, the projection method selected may not be suitable. Just changing to a spherical projection method is not likely to meet your objective. So another approach may be what you need.
